# rails with dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, dropbox

I am doing a ruby on rails project in class with a group and want to add extra gems to my app using dropbox.com. I have dropbox on my computer but once I'm in the terminal, I cant connect to my app. cd Dropbox works fine but cd Dropbox/App gets me -bash: App command not found. Can I gain access to the live folder from the terminal? The directory should be Dropbox/App the way it looks on mac but doesn't work.

*Answer
One of my buddies just gave me the answer. cd ~/Dropbox/my_app works. The tilde key works on a mac.

Comment: That's really cool you're using Rails in school! Most schools are too outdated for that.

Comment: Yea DePaul in Chicago is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but dropbox is a really bad way to share a project. [Git](http://git-scm.com/) is made for this and is pretty easy to get setup with. You can use [GitHub](https://github.com/) to create a central repository and add collaborators to it. [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) is an alternative to GitHub that offers free private repositories.

Comment: This may be true but how easy is it to use Git compared to having dropbox. I never used Git but it would seem many people recommends dropbox more. Thanks for this information. I will take this on to my next project but we are already using dropbox but yes it is frustrating.

Comment: Agreed. Dropbox is ***not*** for source control. Git is.